# Android TTS from code itself - not user input

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, speech

I want to use the TTS service to speak out text messages I have written in the code itself such as:

```
header.setText("Hello!");
```

I saw TTS from user input, but I do not want this.

I have checked these links by the way:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-speech-to-text-api/

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/

But not really what I want.

Comment: Those links are exactly what you should be using. You would just need to make minor modifications so that you can invoke TTS as you have described.

Comment: use `myTextView.getText()` to get the text and then feed that into the tts service.

Comment: @alanv Any place i can see a sample implementation of this perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You can label your element with **contentDescription**.

Java example:

```
myButton.setContentDescription("My text to speech");
```

XML example:

```
<LinearLayout
    .... >
    <ImageView
        ....
        android:contentDescription="My text to speech" />
</LinearLayout>
```